# What changes must be done to use the blackberry application code to work on Blackberry touch?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Hi I have been working on a blackberry app and developed about 90% of the app .But my client wants the app should work on blackberry touch also. So I just wanted to know what changes I will need to do to convert the same code to work on blackberry touch .Please help me I am new to Blackberry app development .

Comment: Are you talking about BlackBerry 10 or BlackBerry OS 7 and before?

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, we are talking about a Java application running on BB7 or earlier OS.

The short answer is, it depends.

If you have used standard RIM controls (buttons, ObjectChoiceField etc.) then these will work on the touch screen with no change.  If you have used your own controls, for example an image button, then these might not work very well - for example the button might not be big enough to be hit easily with a fat finger.

The other problem is the virtual keyboard, it may appear at points when you do not want it to and not appear when you do.  Not a problem on a lot of phones, but remember there are at least 2 non keyboard phones out there, so the Virtual keyboard is the only option for typing.

The best approach is work through each of your screens and try them in the Simulator.  Zoom the Simulator so that it looks like the real device.  And pretend you are using a finger, don't rely on the mouse because you can position the mouse very accurately.

I would raise new questions about specific Fields that you have problems with, rather than continue this with any issues you find.

Comment: Are you sure the question is about BBOS≤7? Question is tagged as blackberry-10.

Comment: @Kernald, it's hard to say.  [His other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18378387/119114) seems to be about the old platform.